# Picpick equivalent for ubuntu?

Tags: screenshot, gnome-screenshot

Does an equivalent for picpick exist for ubuntu? what I saw is ksnip. The problem with that is that it lacks EDITING capabilities. Sometimes I want to cut parts out of the screenshot.

Say, the middle part. Because the interesting parts are on the side.

1. Or make the image bigger, so I can capture a different part of the screen, and paste it inside.
2. Cut parts of a screenshot
3. paste parts of a screenshot (within the screenshot tool)
4. expand canvas
5. contract canvas
6. take multiple screenshots, obviously not just one (without saving. Ksnip can do that)
7. additionally a way to share the screenshot, picpick allows for sharing on imgur and other place, directly from the tool itself.
8. Optimally lets me undo / move drag and drop arrows that I put inside the image easily

Comment: down vote for what?? btw I started using ksnip. It is not as good, but ok so far

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the question is poor. You never mentioned what you really want. Do you think people using Ubuntu know what pickpick is?

Comment: @Pilot6 updated

Answer (score 0):

GIMP is an amazingly versatile image editor that can take screenshots using the GIMP GUI as shown below, cut out complicated shaped pieces from an image like a jigsaw puzzle, select a part of an image and make it transparent, cut, paste, resize images, scale images and much much more. The screenshots appear as tabs in the GIMP canvas area. They not saved or exported unless the user specifically chooses an option to save or export them.

Images can be exported from GIMP to Imgur by installing the [Export to Imgur](https://github.com/tschuy/gimp-export-to-imgur) plugin. To install this plugin, copy upload.py to your GIMP plugins folder. This folder can be found by going to *Edit* -> *Preferences* -> *Folders* -> *Plug-ins*.

GIMP is the best image editor on Ubuntu. I've tried them all and none of them can compare with GIMP.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

To install GIMP image editor in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install gimp
```